# Can a Lipschitz-continuous function take on every value more than $L$ times?

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Here's an interesting question I stumbled upon recently: can a Lipschitz-continuous function $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ with Lipschitz bound $L$ take on every value $y\in[0,1]$ more than $L$ times?

Intuitively, I'd expect the answer to be no, but it's not at all obvious to me how that could be proven. It seems to me like there might necessarily be some measure theory involved, but I'm curious whether a more elementary proof exists as well.

Comment: @Feng so what? (I think it doesn't adress the question.)

Comment: @PrincessEev ? If you give an example where the property does not hold true then this does not rule out that the property holds true for other examples.

Comment: My bad, I misread the question as referring to *any* such function.

Comment: Maybe some well-chosen piecewise-affine function will work (with one of the pieces having exactly a slope of $\pm L$ and the others slopes of $|m| \leq L$)?

Comment: I think the first step of the proof is to show that there is only a denumerable number of values where a function is constant.

Comment: I hope that this time I’m not making mistakes. For $L\in(0,1)$, we can never find such $f$. Indeed, assume that $f(a)$ is the minimum of $f$ and $f(b)$ is the maximum, then $f(b)-f(a)\leq L|b-a|\leq L<1$, which implies that $f$ can not be a surjective. Hence, there exists some $y\in[0,1]$ such that $f$ takes $y$ $0$ times, and $0<L$. Btw, your “more than $L$” means “$>L$“ or “$\geq L$”? Although it doesn’t matter in this comment where $L\in(0,1)$.

Comment: @Feng by "more than" I mean strict inequality, i.e. "$>$". For $L<1$ such a function can indeed not exist for the reason you gave, and for $L=1$ it can also be seen relatively easily that such a function doesn't exist because the only surjective functions with Lipschitz bound $1$ are $x$ and $1-x$. The case $L>1$ is unclear to me though and is what I'm mainly interested in.

Comment: Although I gave a proof below, I would still be very interested in knowing if there is a (more or less) fully elementary proof as well!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a proof using quite a big gun, namely the [Coarea formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarea_formula). This formula shows that
$$
  \int_{(0,1)} |f'(x)| \, dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \# f^{-1}(\{t\}) \, d t,
$$
where $f'(x)$ is the derivative of $f$, which exists almost everywhere by [Rademacher's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher%27s_theorem) and which satisfies $|f'(x)| \leq L$ (whenever it exists) if $f$ is $L$-Lipschitz. In the above formula, we have used that the $0$-dimensional Hausdorff measure is just the counting measure.

Now, first note that the left-hand side satisfies $\int_{(0,1)} |f'(x)| \, dx \leq L$.

But if $f$ takes on each $y \in [0,1]$ strictly more than $L$ times, then this means $\# f^{-1}(\{t\}) > L$ for all $t \in [0,1]$, so that the right-hand side of the equation satisfies
$$
  \int_{\mathbb{R}} \# f^{-1}(\{t\}) \, d t
  \geq \int_{[0,1]} \# f^{-1}(\{t\}) \, d t
  >    L.
$$
In combination, we get the desired contradiction.

Comment: nice :D that first formula is quite similar to what I had in mind, and why I put the measure theory tag on the question - didn't know that there's already a theorem like that though. very interesting answer, thanks!